# What would be the linq for this SQL Group Join

Tags: c#, linq

I use to work in SQL Server ,Having issue in converting same in Linq .
Its a **Group Join in Linq**.

SQL Query :

```
Select 
    Convert(varchar,CreateOn,101),
    count(*),
    Note as Total 
from TrnExpense 
group by Convert(varchar,CreateOn,101),Note 
order by Convert(varchar,CreateOn,101) desc
```

My Output in SQL server follows :

[image]

Output in linq is also accepted same .Any help will be appreciated .

**Class Generated for TrnExpense follows :**

```
public partial class TrnExpense
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TripId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TruckId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TrailerId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DriverId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ReferType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VendorId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ExpenseType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StateId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CityId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Qty { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> qbStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> qbTaxCode { get; set; }
        public string QtyUnit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Rate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PreTaxAmt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Outstanding { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> ServiceFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> HstTax { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> TaxOne { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> TaxTwo { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string CardNo { get; set; }
        public string UnitNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PaymentId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SettlementId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VendorPayId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpenseDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public string OwnerDeductionYN { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PayStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DriverDedStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DriverSettleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UpdateBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AmountPaid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ExpPaymentType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsExcludeTax { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TransferToQBDate { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DocumentUploadId { get; set; }
        public string DeductionTypeFlag { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> NetAmount { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateOn { get; set; }
        public string CreateBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyOn { get; set; }
        public string ModifyBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Rate1Per { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Rate2Per { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> TaxIncluded { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> TaxOnly { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IncludeTax1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IncludeTax2 { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SourceId { get; set; }
        public string QbId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> QbLastSyncDate { get; set; }

        public virtual CityState CityState { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public virtual ExpenseType ExpenseType1 { get; set; }
        public virtual StateCountry StateCountry { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: [This](http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/) is a list of common SQL queries translated to LINQ. It may be a useful reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as a GROUP JOIN in SQL. That's a plain old GROUP BY. It's also badly written, resulting in a full table scan and the wrong sort order. The conversion to string means that the entire table has to be scanned in order to calculate the strtings. If you want to group by dates, either use a `date` column or use `group by cast(CreatedOn as date)`. SQL Server is smart enough to use any indexes on the `datetime` column even if you cast it as a date. Whe you use a locale-specific string though, it has to scan the entire table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .. thanks but.... the output needed is in string or int only .Date format should be same ,As per the current schenerio i am working on.
I do understand what you trying to explain ,But this time the requirement is what i mentioned above .

Comment: @UJS the output. You still don't understand what that query does. You broke the group and order clauses though. Besides - the output to what? Any client can display a `DateTime` using a specific format. You don't know what the correct format is though, until the data gets to the client. **Why** would someone in the UK or Germany want to see a US format?

Comment: Anyway, you can do whatever you want in the `SELECT` clause. The rest though has to be `GROUP BY cast(CreatedOn as date), Note ORDER BY cast(CreateOnd as date) DESC`. Your current results are guaranteed to be wrong. Imagine results from 2017 *and* 2016 - you'd get December 2016 rows *before* March or January 2017 because any string starting with `12` comes before anything starting with `03` or `01`

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = (from t in TrnExpense 
group t by new { t.CreatedOn.Date, t.Note } into g
orderby g.Key.Date descending
select new{
    CreatedOn = g.Key.Date,
    Note = g.Key.Note,
    Count = g.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: you should increase the usefulness of your answer by adding some sentences explaining how this query exactly works.

Comment: Thanks , but i have put the date format 101 which shows only date and neglect the time.
Group by CreateOn should be only date not DateTime

Comment: @UJS that conversion is a big bug. It doesn't show the date, it returns a string which invalidates any indexing and the localized format results in an invalid sort order - did you noticed how October and September dates are mixed up? If you wanted to use only the date part, `cast(CreatedOn as date)` would do the job

Comment: @LiviuBoboia a simple `t.CreatedOn.Date` is enough to cast the `datetime` to a `date`

Comment: i've update the code, i used the Date property because i think that in the model he will have the column mapped to a DateTime

Comment: @LiviuBoboia your entire query is making error .. there is no Date Propery in CreatedOn .

Comment: Could you post the the class that is generated from your TrnExpense table?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code ,Written in lambda expression:

```
var resultSet=TrnExpenses.GroupBy(s=>new 
{
    s.CreateOn.Value.Date, s.Note
})
.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Key.Date)
.Select(s=>new
{
    s.Key.Date,
    s.Key.Note,
    Count = s.Count()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and found the following and simply want to add on :

To access the date From datetime *Column.Value.Date* is used .

Following code will clear the same .

```
(from t in TrnExpenses 
group t by new { t.CreateOn.Value.Date, t.Note } into g
orderby g.Key.Date descending
select new{
    CreatedOn = g.Key.Date,
    Note = g.Key.Note,
    Count = g.Count()
}).ToList()
```

Comment: You don't need `.Value` to access a DateTime value. You need it for nullable types only